# If a matrix $A$ is orthogonal, show that $\Delta(f \circ A) = (\Delta f)\circ A$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, orthogonality, laplacian

Let $O(d)$ be the space of orthogonal $d \times d$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$. These matrices act on $C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, the set of twice continuously differentiable functions $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ with compact support, via $(f \circ A)(x) := f(Ax)$, where $A \in O(d)$. I am trying to show that for all $f \in C_c^2(\mathbb{R}^d) $ and for all $A \in O(d)$, we have $\Delta(f \circ A) = (\Delta f)\circ A$. Here, $\Delta$ denotes the Laplace operator.

I am aware of the hint in the answer given to this related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/983262/the-laplacian-of-the-composition-of-a-function-with-an-orthogonal-transformation), however I am unable to complete the proof. Further hints on how exactly to apply the chain rule, as well as a full proof would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit**: Until now, I have the following: Let $A := (a_{ij})$, $x := (x_1,...,x_d)$. Since $AA^\top = I$, we have
$$ \sum_{j=1}^d a_{ij}a_{kj} = \delta_{ik}, $$
where $\delta_{ik}$ is the Kronecker Delta. We thus have
$$(f \circ A)(x) = f(Ax) = f \left( \sum_{i=1}^da_{1i}x_i,..., \sum_{i=1}^da_{di}x_i\right).$$
We denote $z_i = g_i(x_1,...,x_d) = \sum_{k=1}^da_{ik}x_k$. With the chain rule
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} = \sum_{i=1}^d  \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_i} \frac{\partial z_i}{\partial x_j},$$
we get that
\begin{align} 
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}(f \circ A)(x) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}f(z_1,...,z_d)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^d \frac{\partial f(z_1,...,z_d)}{\partial z_i} \frac{\partial g_i(x_1,...,x_d)}{\partial x_j}\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^d a_{ij} \frac{\partial f(z_1,...,z_d)}{\partial z_i}.
\end{align}
In the next step we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_j^2}(f \circ A)(x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{ij} \frac{\partial f(z_1,...,z_d)}{\partial z_i} \right) = \sum_{i=1}^d a_{ij} \frac{\partial^2 f(z_1,...,z_d)}{\partial x_j \partial z_i},
\end{align}
but I'm not sure if this last step is valid.
Now, if we compute $(\Delta f) \circ A$, we get
\begin{align}
((\Delta f)\circ A)(x) &= (\Delta f)(Ax)\\ 
&= \left( \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_j^2} \right) (z_1,....z_d)\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{\partial^2f(z_1,...,z_d)}{\partial x_j^2},
\end{align}
and since we already computed the first and second partial derivative of $f$, we get that $\Delta(f \circ A) = (\Delta f) \circ A$.

I have two problems:

- I haven't used the fact that $A$ is orthogonal.
- I'm unsure whether or not I'm using the definition of the chain rule correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can just use the Leibniz rule and the chain rule. Doing it twice will give you the double sume that simplifies.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Could you perhaps elaborate? My problem is that I'm not sure how to apply these rules correctly

Comment: I would suggest, you look the precise statement of those rules up and post an attempt how to apply them in your question above. Then we see where you get stuck. In fact showing one's attempts is considered good practice on this site and not doing it results quite often in closing or downvoting the question.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Will do. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: This calculation is part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1523173/80734) answer that I posted a long time ago

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think part of your confusion stems from the use of $\partial /\partial_{z_j}$. It might be easier to see it, when you use the partial derivative $\partial_j$ (meaning you take the partial derivative with respect to the $j$th slot of the function). You have correctly computed

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx_j} (f\circ A)(x) &= \frac{d}{dx_j} f( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i ) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^d (\partial_k f)( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i ) \cdot \frac{d}{dx_j} \left( \sum_{\ell=1}^d a_{k\ell} x_\ell\right) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^d a_{kj} \cdot (\partial_k f)( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i )
\end{align}

Repeating the same argument with $\partial_k f$ instead of $f$ leads to

\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dx_j^2} (f\circ A)(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^d a_{kj} \cdot \frac{d}{dx_j} (\partial_k f)( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i ) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^d a_{kj} \sum_{\ell=1}^d a_{\ell j} (\partial_\ell \partial_k f)( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i )
\end{align}

Thus, using your equation for the coefficients we get

\begin{align}
\Delta (f\circ A)(x) &= \sum_{j=1}^d \frac{d^2}{dx_j^2} (f\circ A)(x) \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^d \sum_{k=1}^d a_{kj} \sum_{\ell=1}^d a_{\ell j} (\partial_\ell \partial_k f)( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i ) \\
&= \sum_{k,\ell=1}^d \left( \sum_{j=1}^d a_{kj} a_{\ell j} \right) (\partial_\ell \partial_k f)( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i ) \\
&= \sum_{k,\ell=1}^d \delta_{k,\ell} (\partial_\ell \partial_k f)( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i ) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^d (\partial_k^2 f)( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i ) \\
&= (\Delta f) ( \sum_{i=1}^d a_{1i} x_i, \dots, \sum_{i=1}^d a_{di} x_i ) \\
&= (\Delta f)(Ax) \\
&= ((\Delta f)\circ A)(x)
\end{align}

Comment: I changed your answer to use `\begin{align}` and `\end{align}` for readability. I hope you don't mind!

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you very much! It looks so much better.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Wonderful, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @jasnee You're welcome. Is it clear now, where you went wrong?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Yes. I should have repeated the argument exactly as in step 1 with $\partial_k f$ instead of $f$. I failed to apply the chain rule correctly, so it led to this weird expression with just one sum, instead of the expression that you got

Comment: @jasnee Great! It is in the beginning quite confusing with all those indices (at least it was so for me). With time it will get easier.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you very much!!!

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín Glad you like it!

Answer (score 1):

$
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm d}
\newcommand\tr{\mathop{\mathrm{tr}}}
$Here is a coordinate-free proof.

The Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient; the gradient is defined to be the unique function such that
$$
  v\cdot\nabla g(x) = \dd g_x(v)
$$
for all vectors $v$ and $x$ and where $\dd g_x$ is the total derivative of $g$ at $x$. It is easiest to apply the chain rule using the total derivative:
$$
  v\cdot\nabla[f\circ A](x) = \dd[f\circ A]_x(v) = \dd f_{Ax}(\dd A_x(v)) \overset{(1)}= \dd f_{Ax}(Av) = (Av)\cdot[\nabla f](Ax) \overset{(2)}= v\cdot(A^{-1}[\nabla f](Ax))
$$
(1) follows because the derivative of a linear transformation is itself; (2) follows because $A$ is orthogonal. Thus
$$
  \nabla[f\circ A] = A^{-1}\circ[\nabla f]\circ A.
$$
Now we want to take the divergence of this, but the divergence is the trace of the total derivative; applying this fact and the chain rule gives
$$
  \Delta[f\circ A](x) = \tr\dd\bigl[A^{-1}\circ[\nabla f]\circ A\bigr]_x = \tr A^{-1}\circ\dd[\nabla f]_{Ax}\circ A = \tr\dd[\nabla f]_{Ax} = [\nabla\cdot\nabla f](Ax) = [\Delta f](Ax).
$$

Comment: Maybe another way to state the idea would be: the Laplacian can be expressed as a composition of $d : \Omega^0 \to \Omega^1$, the duality isomorphism $\Omega^1 \to \Omega^{n-1}$, and $d : \Omega^{n-1} \to \Omega^n$.  However, $d$ is coordinate-free, whereas the duality isomorphism depends only on the inner product (Riemannian manifold structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$), and the idea of an orthogonal matrix is precisely that it gives an automorphism of the inner product space.